# Is there any Korean word in use that uses 藍 / '남' to mean 바구니 / basket?

Tags: hanja

When looking at the hanja for '남' on my Windows IME I was surprised to see '바구니 남' as the third entry. I couldn't find a Korean word that uses 藍 / '남' to mean 바구니 / basket. Are there any examples of Korean words that use this character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most commonly-used word that includes 대바구니 람 is 요람(cradle). 
And there are some words spin-offed from the word like,

- 요람지(cradleland)
- 요람처(synonym of 요람지)
- 요람기(babyhood)

The character is also used in these words.

- 죽람(bamboo basket)
- 어람(A basket which is used to contain fish)
- 와람(Bohemian Waxwing)

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a mistake.
There are two similar characters:

> 藍 - 쪽 람 - means indigo - found in the word 남색 (indigo colour)
>
> 籃 - 바구니 람 - means basket

The difference between these can be difficult to see, but the radical is different - 쪽 람 has the "plant" radical 艹, and 바구니 람 has the "bamboo" radical 竹.

Both of these will be pronounced 남 when found at the beginning of a word.

Using the Windows Korean IME, typing 람 + 한자 key gives 藍 쪽 람 as the 3rd choice, but typing 남 + 한자 key gives 藍 바구니 남 as the 3rd choice - it appears the two characters got mixed up here.

As for your original question, looking in the [Naver 한자 사전](http://hanja.naver.com/) gives just one word: 籃輿 (남여), a kind of "[palanquin](http://terms.naver.com/entry.nhn?docId=1075192&cid=40942&categoryId=32197)" or cart carried by 2 people on mountain roads.